# why software is not working after turn it into exe file?

Tags: python, exe

I have made a simple text to speech software by python and turned it into exe file by `pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py`this code in cmd. But after making it an exe file, when i run the software it does nothing... would you guys please help me in this issue?
Here is code if it needs::

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import pyttsx3

def speak():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.getProperty("rate")
    engine.setProperty("rate", 100)
    audio_string = text.get('0.0', END)
    if audio_string:
        engine.say(audio_string)
        engine.runAndWait()
        engine.stop()

def save_aud():
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    audio_string = text.get('0.0', END)
    if audio_string:
        engine.save_to_file(audio_string, 'sound.mp3')
        engine.runAndWait()
        engine.stop()
        showinfo('Python says', 'file is saved')

root = Tk()
root.title("Text To Speech")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.configure(bg='white')

text = ScrolledText(root, width=30, height=10, wrap=WORD, padx=10, pady=10, bd=5, relief= RIDGE)
text.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

ttk.Button(root, text='Listen', width=7, command=speak).grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=2)
ttk.Button(root, text='Clear', width=7, command=lambda: text.delete('0.0', END)).grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=2)
ttk.Button(root, text='save', width=7, command=save_aud).grid(row=1, column=2, ipadx=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "_when i run the software it does nothing_" ~ Can you elaborate this?

Comment: Wrapping a Python program in an `.exe` is a lot more complex than you might imagine. The `pyinstaller` documentation has a very helpful section called *When things go wrong.* I suggest you work through that.

Comment: then its not a simple task i guess....being a newbie here i couldn't realize then

Comment: "when i run the software it does nothing" it means when i double click on the exe file it opens but when i put the texts to  convert text to speech....it doesn't work

Comment: @Ashik can you try running it through the command line? Check if there is a stack trace message